# Upload file using Jetty and Maven

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I want to use Jetty to upload file to my server I have tried the example from the [Jetty documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/File+Upload+in+jetty6), but it doesn't work. It throws an exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mortbay.servlet.MultiPartFilter
```

Comment: Perhaps this [File Upload in jetty6 tutorial](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/File+Upload+in+jetty6) can help?

Comment: Perhaps you could paste your pom file (or at least the relative bits of it).

Comment: @Raghuram: i using this tutorial and got this error
the pom i use in this example:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty_and_Maven_HelloWorld

Answer (score 1):

Since you say your using Eclipse Jetty the correct [class package](http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/jetty-servlets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/MultiPartFilter.java) is:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.MultiPartFilter
```

**Note that using the filter is not recommended for jetty-8 since the Servlet 3.0 spec added an alternative way to access this sort of information through the servlet API.**